# How to combine Linq query results

Tags: linq

I need to be able to add an unkown number of where clauses to a Linq query. Currently I have been trying to combine the queries using Concat(). For example:

```
var r1 =
    from field in db.fields
    where ID == 1
    select field;

var r2 = 
    from field in db.fields
    where ID == 2
    select field

var r3 = r1.Concat(r2);
```

This is giving me odd results, so I know that there must be a better way to do this. Is there any way to do something along the lines of an "accumulating result"; such as:

```
r1 = r1 + r2
```

Where r1 gets all of the results it had before plus all of the results from r2. This would allow me to iterate through a list of "where" filters and combine them as an OR statement would. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the Union operator:

```
var r1 = Context.Fields.Where<FieldObject>(f => f.ID == 1).Select<FieldObject, Field>(f => f.Field);
var r2 = Context.Fields.Where<FieldObject>(f => f.ID == 2).Select<FieldObject, Field>(f => f.Field);
var r3 = r1.Union<Field>(r2);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying to do *r1 = r1 + r2*, then you should use some **[immediate query execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx)** behavior, like `ToList`. You see, In LINQ the query is executed only if needed, and not at the place it was defined. 
So the query should look like

```
r1 = r1.Union(r2).ToList()
```

Also, notice the use of **Union** instead of Concat. "Concat method returns all the original elements in the input sequences. The Union method returns only unique elements." (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx))

EDIT: Or you could use [**PredicateBuilder**](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build the OR-ed predicate, somthing like

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Field>();
foreach(Expression<Func<Field,Boolean>> filt in filters){
  predicate = predicate.Or(filt);
}
var result = db.fields.Where(predicate);
```